# Конечные поля, многочлены и двоичная арифметика. Криптография

Tags: c, математика, криптография

Недавно я реализовал криптосистему Мэсси-Омуры в Maple, и вместо числового поля (которое везде приводится для простоты) использовал поле многочленов.  На чистом Си реализация заняла бы несколько месяцев, поэтому я писал в Maple. Теперь хочу написать этот же алгоритм на Си, но мне нужно разобраться, как на низком уровне производить операции над многочленами в конечном поле характеристики 2 (в этой криптосистеме огромное количество возведений многочленов в степень).

Нашел вот такую ссылку: http://frogs.digdes.ru/netcat_files/1162_42.pdf
Но здесь маловато информации и, видимо, нужны фундаментальные знания в архитектуре процессоров и знание того, как процессоры выполняют операции над числами.

Идея реализации полиномиальных операций в том, что мы работаем с двоичными многочленами как с числами. Например, многочлену x^4 + x^2 + x + 1 можно поставить в соответствие его вектор коэффициентов 00010111. Этот вектор можно рассмотреть как разложение числа 23 в двоичной системе счисления. Операциям над многочленами соответствуют операции над такими числами, которые однозначно им соответствуют. Сложение двух многочленов - это сложение двух таких чисел.

В этой криптосистеме многочлен, которым замаркировано сообщение, многократно умножается на себя и результат приводится по модулю примитивного многочлена, корень которого порождает конечное поле. Это легко вычислить на бумажке, но как эти операции реализовать на Си?

Короче, мне нужно написать библиотеку основных функций для вычислений в полях Галуа. Использовать готовые мне неинтересно. Посоветуйте какие-нибудь материалы, которые мне помогут. Также будет полезна информация, которая поможет разобраться в статье по первой ссылке.

Если кому-то будет интересно, вот реализация трехпроходного протокола Мэсси-Омуры в Maple 15 Classic Worksheet. http://rghost.ru/76v6gyKb8

Comment: Непонятно, в чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Как реализовать операции над многочленами из конечного поля: возведение в степень и приведение по модулю другого многочлена.

Comment: Опишите, что у вас не получается.

Comment: Кстати, вот что интересно. В аддитивной группе поля каждый многочлен к себе противоположный, то есть f + f = 0. Вот пример: (x^4 + x^2 + x + 1) + (x^4 + x^2 + x + 1) = 2x^4 + 2x^2 + 2x + 2. Т.к. в двоичном поле 2 = 0, то результат сложения - ноль. Однако 23 + 23 = 46 = 0010 1110. Этому вектору коэффициентов соответствует многочлен x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x. А должно получиться 0.

Comment: "Опишите, что у вас не получается." Я вообще не понимаю, как реализовать эти операции. В интернете материалов практически нет. Есть статья Криса Касперски, но он, похоже, сам не понимает то, про что рассказывает. Большинство его статей - просто копипаст и перевод.

Comment: Я думаю, что этот вопрос будет закрыт, как слишком общий.

Comment: Нет, вопрос вполне конкретный: реализация по крайней мере возведения в степень в конечном поле многочленов. А шифрование и дешифрование в криптосистеме Мэсси-Омуры очень простое: возведение в степень e (шифрование) или d(дешифрование).

Comment: Если здесь никто не поможет, куда можно обратиться? Есть ли смысл в 2015 году идти на exploit.in? Вся эта ИБшная тусовка давно мертва. Старики ушли в мирное русло, а молодым это все неинтересно. Как только дело касается криптографии, становится ясно, что всем вокруг плевать.

Comment: Лично я впервые слышу о exploit.in, так как никогда с ним не имел дела. Наверное вам надо искать форумы, специально посвященные методам криптографии.

Comment: На эксплойте есть раздел про крптографию, но на этом форуме сейчас сидит 2.5 человека. Других форумов я не знаю. И вряд ли на таких форумах кто-то разбирается в криптоматематике. У писателей вирусни криптография ограничивается ксором одних функций с другими.

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Разбейте его на части. Попробуйте вычленить элементарные операции и спросите, как они реализовываются.

Comment: Думаю вам пригодится информация о битовых операция [[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Битовые_операции]] Но если бы вы написали в математичкской форме какие операции вам необходимы, то было бы легче помочь.